# Add IF Statement to SUMPRODUCT Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently using a SUMPRODUCT formula to count the occurrences by month and year of an event. I have copied this below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Sheet2!$G$2:$G$10000)=E17)*(YEAR(Sheet2!$G$2:$G$10000)=D17))
```

I now need to modify this formula so that it only shows occurrences if another cell contains certain text, this is shown below:

```
    =SUMPRODUCT(IF(Sheet2!$O$2:$O$10000="Category",
(MONTH(Sheet2!$G$2:$G$10000)=E17)*(YEAR(Sheet2!$G$2:$G$10000)=D17),0))
```

This is not returning the correct number and I do not know what is the best way is to fix the formula.

I have looked online for a fix, and nothing seems to be helping. I have created multiple versions of this formula, but all come up with `#VALUE`.

Comment: Why are you using `SumProduct()` if you are doing the multiplication yourself? Instead of `SUMPRODUCT(Month(...) * Year(...))`, why don't you do `SUMPRODUCT(Month(...) , Year(...))`? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2016+, it's easiear to use SUMIFS. If you want to continue using SUMPRODUCT, I'll explain the idea:

- Excel evaluates conditionals to 0 (FALSE) or 1 (TRUE). For example:

```
YEAR(Sheet2!$G$2:$G$10000)=D17
```

Will evaluate to 1 when the year of the cell in the range equals de value of D17, and 0 otherwhise.

So, if you multiply conditions, you can and more restraints:

```
    (MONTH(Sheet2!$G$2:$G$10000)=E17)) * (YEAR(Sheet2!$G$2:$G$10000) = D17)
```

Will evaluate to 1 when:
- the year of the cell in the range equals de value of D17 AND the month of the cell in the range equals E17, 0 otherwise.

If you want to add another condition, just add another factor in the SUMPRODUCT with the condition. Meaning:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    (MONTH(Sheet2!$G$2:$G$10000) = E17) *
    (YEAR(Sheet2!$G$2:$G$10000)  = D17) * 
    (Sheet2!$O$2:$O$10000        = "Category")
)
```

By the way, the way it's being used, the SUMPRODUCT is doing the same as SUM.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gustavo. I have tried this with the spreadsheet and it is returning 0 for all columns. Do you have any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Does the "Category" column have to be a specific cell type? I have changed it around and it is still coming up blank.